# Rendering a Compound view created in JAVA/Kotlin file in a XML

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview, android-custom-view

I am creating a view in my Kotlin file and setting some properties like text color and typeface.
[image]

```
class TestTextView(context: Context) : AppCompatTextView(context) {

    init{
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark))
    }
}
```

Now when I use this view in an XML and try to render it, it does not show blue color

```
<com.mindvalley.core.view.TestTextView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Adding screenshot for the same. Is there a way to render the exact color, size and typeface TextView created in Kotlin file in an XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Views in Android have multiple constructors.

```
public AppCompatTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public AppCompatTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
}

public AppCompatTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(TintContextWrapper.wrap(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);

    mBackgroundTintHelper = new AppCompatBackgroundHelper(this);
    mBackgroundTintHelper.loadFromAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);

    mTextHelper = new AppCompatTextHelper(this);
    mTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mTextHelper.applyCompoundDrawablesTints();

    mTextClassifierHelper = new AppCompatTextClassifierHelper(this);
}
```

When the view is inflated from xml file, the constructor with -at least- attributes is used, and you don't override this one.

**When defining a custom view you should override each of the super class constructors**, or just the richest one putting `@JvmOverloads` annotation before.

⚠️ It's an annotation to use with caution:
https://medium.com/@mmlodawski/https-medium-com-mmlodawski-do-not-always-trust-jvmoverloads-5251f1ad2cfe

Comment: Tried overriding all the default methods but the XML preview does not show blue color.
P.S. Blue color actually appears when I run the app. I want to also see blue color in preview of XML in Android Studio.